Eliminate $y,z$: $x^3+y^3=x^2-y^2$, $y^3+z^3=y^2-z^2$, $z^3+x^3=z^2-x^2$
Given the system of equations $(x,y,z\in\mathbb{C}-\{0\})$:
$x=(x-y)^2+y(x+1)$
$y=(y-z)^2+z(y+1)$
$z=(z-x)^2+x(z+1)$
Eliminate the variables $y,z$.
Adding the equations we have that:
$2(x^2+y^2+z^2)=xy+yz+zx$
Approach 1: From the first and second equations we can solve for the variables $y,z$ in terms of $x$ and replace them in the second equation but it becomes very complicated.
Approach 2: Simplifying and multiplying by $(x+y)$ we have to:
$x^3+y^3=x^2-y^2$
$y^3+z^3=y^2-z^2$
$z^3+x^3=z^2-x^2$
Adding the equations we have that:
$x^3+y^3+z^3=0$
Approach 3: Using wolframalpha $x$ must satisfy the equation: $x^6+ 3 x^4+ 6 x^2+15=0$.
Any hint would be appreciated.

The following treatment relies on resultants. It first takes equations 2) and 3) and produces a resultant in $x$ and $y$. The second step is, in  that resultant,  the reduction of all powers in $y$ to linear terms in $y$, where eq. 1) is used.  In the third step, the squared version of the resultant is again reduced  to linear terms in $y$, where eq. 1) is used. In the fourth step, the linear terms in $y$ in step 2 and 3 are eliminated, giving a resultant in $x$. In the fifth step, spurious solutions are eliminated.
Step 1:
Consider the  equations 2) and 3) :
\begin{align}
&  y^2 + z^2 -y z + z - y =0 \quad \tag{2} \\
&  x^2 + z^2 - xz + x - z =0 \quad \tag{3}
\end{align}
Subtracting gives $ z(x-y+2) = x+y+x^2 - y^2$. Using that and taking $(x-y+2)^2 * $(eq 2) gives
$$
(x - y + 2)^2 (y^2 - y) + (y + x + x^2 - y^2)^2 + (1 - y) (y + x + x^2 - y^2) (x - y + 2)= 0 $$
or, expanded,
$$
R(x,y) = x^4 - x^3 y + 3 x^3 - 3 x^2 y + 4 x^2 - x y^3 + 3 x y^2 - 4 x y + 2 x + y^4 - 3 y^3 + 4 y^2 - 2 y = 0
$$
This is the resultant in $x$ and $y$.
Step 2
Now, in  that resultant,  we reduce all powers in $y$ to linear terms in $y$, where eq. 1) is used. Eq. 1) has the form
$$
w = y^2  = x y + x - y - x^2  \quad \tag{1}
$$
This can be inserted into the resultant which is
$$
R(x,y) = x^4 - x^3 y + 3 x^3 - 3 x^2 y + 4 x^2 - x y w + 3 x w - 4 x y + 2 x + w^2 - 3 y w + 4 w - 2 y  
$$
to give
$$
R(x,y)  = 2 x^4 - 2 x^3 y - 2 x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 4 x^2 - 4 x y^2 - 8 x y + 6 x + 4 y^2 - 6 y
$$
Performing this again is
$$ R(x,y)  = 2 x^4 - 2 x^3 y - 2 x^3 + 6 x^2 y + 4 x^2 - 4 x w - 8 x y + 6 x + 4 w - 6 y
$$
which gives finally, with all terms linear in $y$:
$$ R_1(x,y)  = (2 x^4  + 2 x^3  - 4 x^2 + 10 x) + y(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 ) = 0
$$
Step 3:
With the last version of the resultant, also the version with squared terms holds, however introducing spurious solutions:
$$ R_2(x,y)  = (2 x^4  + 2 x^3  - 4 x^2 + 10 x)^2 - y^2(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )^2 = 0
$$
The spurious solutions arrive since $ R_2(x,y)$ also includes the undesired (red) solutions to $(2 x^4  + 2 x^3  - 4 x^2 + 10 x) \color{red}{-} y(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 ) = 0$.
Now, again $y^2$ can be linearized as above:
$$
R_2(x,y) = (2 x^4  + 2 x^3  - 4 x^2 + 10 x)^2 - (x -x^2)(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )^2 - y (x-1) (- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )^2 = 0
$$
Expanding gives:
$$
R_2(x,y) = (8 x^8 - 4 x^7 + 60 x^5 - 24 x^4 - 40 x^3 + 200 x^2 - 100 x)  + y (1-x) (- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )^2 =0
$$
Step 4:
Having now two equations for the resultant which are linear in $y$, we have the type
\begin{align}
&  R_1(x,y) = a + b y =0  \\
&   R_2(x,y) = c + d y =0
\end{align}
where $\{a,b,c,d\}$ are functions of $x$ only. This set is solved for the resultant in $x$,
$Q(x) = a d - b c = 0$.  Plugging this in gives
\begin{align}
&  (2 x^4  + 2 x^3  - 4 x^2 + 10 x) (1-x) (- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )^2 \\
& - (8 x^8 - 4 x^7 + 60 x^5 - 24 x^4 - 40 x^3 + 200 x^2 - 100 x)(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )  =0
\end{align}
We can hold out a factor $(- 10  - 2 x^3  + 2 x^2 )$ and expand the remainder to obtain
$$
Q(x) = 8 x^2 (x^3 -  x^2 + 5) (x^6 + 3 x^4 + 6 x^2 + 15) = 0
$$
Step 5
The last result contains spurious solutions in the  bracket $(x^3 -  x^2 + 5)$  (see addendum below*). The actual nonzero solutions  are given by
$$
Q^*(x) =  x^6 + 3 x^4 + 6 x^2 + 15 = 0
$$
as was already predicted in the task description. $Q^*(x)$ has six complex solutions. $\qquad \square$

*Addendum:
Suppose $x^3-x^2+5=0$ were to give a correct solution. Then rearranging the equation
$x^3+y^3=x^2-y^2$
would give
$x^3-x^2=-5=-y^3-y^2$,
from which $y$ would solve $y^3+y^2-5=0$. But, since the system is invariant under cyclic permutation of $(x,y,z)$, this would imply that the solution also contains roots of $x^3+x^2-5=0$, which is contradicted by the given factorization.
The factor $x^6+3x^4+6x^2+15$ avoids this contradiction by not mixing even and odd powers of $x$.

I added a proof of thexspurioys roots, feel free to roll back.

Thanks Andreas for your  solution, we also notice that if in the equation (1)  multiply by $(10+2x^3-2x^2)^2$ and replace $R_1(x,y)$ results: $4x^2(x^6+ 3 x^4+ 6 x^2+15)=0$ but in this case there are no spurious roots.

@OscarLanzi Thanks Oscar for the addendum, this is very useful.
